# can't save to database with hidden field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models, one of patients and another of indicadions, I think I have the relationships between the models correctly placed, what I cannot make it work is that the patient_id is placed in the hidden field

my models:

patient: has_many :prescription, dependent: :destroy

indication: belongs_to :patient

my view:

```
<%= form_with(model: prescription) do |form| %>
  <% if prescription.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(prescription.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this prescription from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% prescription.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :patient_id, value: "patient_id" %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :content %>
    <%= form.text_area :content, class:'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <%= form.submit "SAVE",class:'btn save' %>
 
<% end %>
```

The controller:

```
class PrescriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_prescription, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /prescriptions or /prescriptions.json
  def index
    @prescriptions = Prescription.all
  end

  # GET /prescriptions/1 or /prescriptions/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /prescriptions/new
  def new
    @prescription = Prescription.new
  end

  # GET /prescriptions/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /prescriptions or /prescriptions.json
  def create
    @prescription = Prescription.new(prescription_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @prescription.save
        format.html { redirect_to @prescription, notice: "La receta se creó con éxito." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @prescription }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @prescription.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /prescriptions/1 or /prescriptions/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @prescription.update(prescription_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @prescription, notice: "Prescription was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @prescription }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @prescription.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /prescriptions/1 or /prescriptions/1.json
  def destroy
    @prescription.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to prescriptions_url, notice: "Prescription was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_prescription
      @prescription = Prescription.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def prescription_params
      params.require(:prescription).permit(:content, :patient_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: this form suggests a third model is present, `Prescription`. You have mentioned `Patient` and `Indication`. Perhaps we can assume that a patient has_many prescriptions? Can you share the contents of `PrescriptionController` `new` and `create` methods.

Comment: How is it not working? what's the error? what's the controller?

Comment: Is prescription non indication sorry. The controller is the one generated with the scaffold:

Comment: Also, check the parameters being returned when you submit the form. You may find that this hidden field isn't being stored quite how you think it is in the parameters. (Using byebug or similar may help get this information, if you're not using it already.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a hidden input you might actually want to nest the routes to makes the relationship explicit instead of implicit:

```
resources :patients do
  resources :perscriptions, shallow: true
end
```

```
class PrescriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_patient
  before_action :set_prescription, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /patients/1/prescriptions or /patients/1/prescriptions.json
  def index
    @prescriptions = @patient.perscriptions
  end

  # GET /prescriptions/1 or /prescriptions/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /patients/1/prescriptions/new
  def new
    @prescription = Prescription.new
  end

  # GET /prescriptions/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /patients/1/prescriptions or /patients/1/prescriptions.json
  def create
    @prescription = @patient.perscriptions.new(prescription_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @prescription.save
        format.html { redirect_to @prescription, notice: "La receta se creó con éxito." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @prescription }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @prescription.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /prescriptions/1 or /prescriptions/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @prescription.update(prescription_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @prescription, notice: "Prescription was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @prescription }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @prescription.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /prescriptions/1 or /prescriptions/1.json
  def destroy
    @prescription.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to prescriptions_url, notice: "Prescription was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_patient
      @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    end   
 
    def set_prescription
      @prescription = Prescription.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def prescription_params
      params.require(:prescription).permit(:content)
    end
end
```

```
<%= form_with(model: [@patient, @perscription]) do |form| %>
  <% if prescription.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(prescription.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this prescription from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% prescription.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :content %>
    <%= form.text_area :content, class:'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <%= form.submit "SAVE", class:'btn save' %>
 
<% end %>
```